# Typescript knockout filter list

Tags: knockout.js, typescript, knockout-2.0

I have problem with knockout and I cannot figure it out. I need a simple filter. My problem is I always see all the items from self.Vouchers(). The filter is not working and chekboxes seem to have only one-way databinding; if I change a value in the script, it is OK, but I can not change checked on webpage.

Viemodel:

```
function AppViewModel() {
var self = this;

self.FilterVouchersA = ko.observable<boolean>(true);
self.FilterVouchersB = ko.observable<boolean>(false);
self.FilterVouchersC = ko.observable<boolean>(false);

self.Vouchers = ko.observableArray<VoucherModel>();
self.FilteredVouchers = ko.computed(() => {
    var vouchersArray = self.Vouchers();
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(vouchersArray, (voucher: VoucherModel) =>
    (
        self.FilterVouchersA && voucher.type() == VoucherType.A ||
        self.FilterVouchersB && voucher.type() == VoucherType.B ||
        self.FilterVouchersC && voucher.type() == VoucherType.C
    ));
});
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel())
```

Razor:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: FilterVouchersA " /> Voucher type A
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: FilterVouchersB " /> Voucher type B
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: FilterVouchersC " /> Voucher type C

<div id="Complications" class="Complications" data-bind="foreach: FilteredVouchers ">
 .... //Not important
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just not grouping your logic correctly, try adding parens:

```
return ko.utils.arrayFilter(vouchersArray, (voucher: VoucherModel) =>
(
    (self.FilterVouchersA && voucher.type() == VoucherType.A) ||
    (self.FilterVouchersB && voucher.type() == VoucherType.B) ||
    (self.FilterVouchersC && voucher.type() == VoucherType.C)
)
```

If that doesn't work, step into your filter function and make sure it's doing what you want.  The rest is fine.

Comment: When using more than two boolean statements to get a result, you need to be as explicit as possible.  I would take your solution one step further:     (self.FilterVouchersA && (voucher.type() == VoucherType.A)) ||
    (self.FilterVouchersB && (voucher.type() == VoucherType.B)) ||
    (self.FilterVouchersC && (voucher.type() == VoucherType.C))